# Angular Unit Test Using SetInterval

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I don't get it how to write unit test for setInterval. I have function in .component.ts like this

```
startTimer() {
this.showResend = false;
this.otpError = false;
this.time = 60;
this.interval = setInterval(() => {
  this.time--;
  if (this.time < 1) {
    this.endTimer();
  }
}, 1000);
```

}

and I set interval variable same value like variable time, the code look like this

```
      it('start timer function', () => {
      component.startTimer();
      expect(component.showResend).toBeFalsy();
      expect(component.otpError).toBeFalsy()
      expect(component.time).toEqual(60);
      expect(component.interval).toEqual(60)
      })
```

But in interval value is always changing. Can you help me how to write the code correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your test in a [fakeAsynce](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync) zone and use the [tick](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/tick)():

```
 it('start timer function', fakeAsync(() => {
      component.startTimer();
      expect(component.showResend).toBeFalsy();
      expect(component.otpError).toBeFalsy();
      tick(1000); // After this you need to call detectChanges()
      expect(component.time).toEqual(59);
      }));
```

To test it better, parameterize startTimer() like below:

```
startTimer(time: number) {
this.showResend = false;
this.otpError = false;
this.interval = setInterval(() => {
  time--;
  if (this.time < 1) {
    this.endTimer();
  }
}, 1000);
```

and then in your test:

```
it('start timer function', fakeAsync(() => {
      const time = 2;
      component.startTimer(time);
      expect(component.showResend).toBeFalsy();
      expect(component.otpError).toBeFalsy();
      tick(1000); // After this you need to call detectChanges()
      expect(component.time).toEqual(time - 1);
 }));
```